# RecyclerView - change text on clicked item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to change the text only in the specific item that I clicked a button on.
right now - only the last`s item text is changing.

my code:

```
class MyMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<FoodItem> mDataset; /// the list of feedlistings for the adapter
    private Context context;
    private TextView foodTitle, foodPrice, foodType, foodNumber;
    private ImageView foodImage;
    private LinearLayout minusLayout, plusLayout;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            foodPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_food_price);
            foodTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_food_title);
            foodType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_food_type);
            foodImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_meal_image);
            foodNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_food_number);
            minusLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.minus_food_button);
            plusLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.plus_food_button);
            minusLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            plusLayout.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();


            switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.minus_food_button:


                    if (!foodNumber.getText().equals("0")) {

                        try {
                            int myNum;
                            myNum = Integer.parseInt(foodNumber.getText().toString()) - 1;
                            foodNumber.setText(myNum + "");
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                        }
                    }

                    break;


                case R.id.plus_food_button:


                    try {
                        int myNum;
                        myNum = Integer.parseInt(foodNumber.getText().toString()) + 1;
                        foodNumber.setText(myNum + "");
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                    }


                    break;

            }



        }
    }


    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyMenuAdapter(Context context, List<FoodItem> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyMenuAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }


    // set all the layout things here

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        foodTitle.setText(mDataset.get(position).getFOOD_TITLE());
        foodType.setText(mDataset.get(position).getFOOD_TYPE());
        foodPrice.setText(mDataset.get(position).getFOOD_PRICE() + "");
        Picasso.with(context).load(mDataset.get(position).getFOOD_IMAGE()).into(foodImage);


    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Already tried to create the reference of the textview inside the onclick method but then nullPointerException happends.

Comment: Could you post stacttrace?

Comment: There is no exception right now..

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `TextView` directly in your onClick, which puts you at the mercy of the recycler.  That's why you only see the change in the last item.

The way to do this is to update a value in the adapter model and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  From looking at your `onBindViewHolder()`, it seems that you don't have the value of `foodNumber` modeled anywhere in your adapter.

First you need to add a data structure in your adapter to hold the current values for `foodNumber`.  Then in your `onBindViewHolder()`, set the text of `foodNumber` to the current value for that item.  In your `onClick()`, you increment or decrement the current value for that item in the adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (or `notifyItemChanged()` instead to refresh just that view).  This will make the `RecyclerView` refresh and call `onBindViewHolder()`, picking up the new value for `foodNumber`.

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid refreshing the Recycler everytime I need to change a single string. Is that the only way?

Comment: Yes.  The problem is that you don't have control over when the view for that item is created or recycled.  The `RecyclerView` can create/recycle/destroy views essentially at random based on how the user scrolls.  And refreshing is not as inefficient as it sounds. The `RecyclerView` only needs to update the item views that are currently visible.  It won't worry about any other views until the user scrolls and makes them visible.  If you *want* to help the `RecyclerView` update a little more efficiently, you can call `notifyItemChanged()` so that it knows to update only the view for that item.

Answer (score 0):

please read full solution here,

if u want to change text on particular position of textview then it can be done only in activity in which you set adapter.there is nothing to do in adapter only set position from ArrayList.

In Activity

```
private Recycle_Adapter  adapter;

adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new Recycle_FrameAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                     if(position == 1){
                        tv_module.setText("");
                    }
                    else if{

                         }
                       continue up to last


                }
            });
```